# Can Asciidoctor render a separate HTML page per chapter?

Tags: asciidoctor

If I have something like the following:

```
The Manual
====================
Gregg Bolinger
v1.0, 2014-15
:doctype: book
:icons: font
:imagesdir: images

Preamble paragraph

include::chapter1.ad[]

include::chapter2.ad[]
```

I'd like so that each chapter renders in its own HTML file and is linked to from the TOC rather than everything being in a single book.html, for example. It seems to generate separate files already, but that's only because they are in the source directory. It is still combining everything into a single HTML page. I'm using the Gradle Asciidoctor plugin, if that helps to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless there's something in the gradle plugin that does chunked html, asciidoctor does not handle chunked output at the moment. It's on the [list of things to do](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor/issues/626), but it hasn't been done. If you look at the issue, however, someone has create a custom script/converter to do it though, perhaps that will work for your case as well.

Comment: There seems to be no progress on native multipage HTML output so far. I'm not sufficiently seasoned in ruby to make that script work. An explicit example would help me a lot.

Comment: If you're more comfortable in a Java environment, use asciidoctorj which wraps all the ruby stuff in a Java layer. I personally don't have an example of an extension doing chunked html.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [asciidoctor-multipage](https://github.com/owenh000/asciidoctor-multipage) extension, each chapter can be rendered in its own HTML file. The links in the TOC points to the respective HTML chapters rather than everything being in a single book.html. At the end of every HTML page, the extension also adds links to the next or previous page, as seen on [this website](https://owenh.net/static/portfolio/nxlog/guide/introduction.html).

Assuming you have already installed the asciidoctor, just do `$ gem install asciidoctor-multipage` in your command line to install the multipage extension.

After making your `file-name.adoc` with various chapters, `$ cd`  to that folder and then do `$ asciidoctor -r asciidoctor-multipage -b multipage_html5 -D test/out --backend multipage_html5 -a data-uri file-name.adoc`. This command will embed any images in the `file-name.adoc` to the new `.html` files which will be saved in newly created `test/out` folder. I only tested this using Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

As Sam Macharia answered, asciidoctor-multipage can achieve your goal.

Also, most Docbook toolchains let you control how content is "chunked" into HTML pages, including at the book, chapter, and section levels.

[Antora](https://antora.org/) is the "official" way to achieve your goal.